# Wait for the first finished/failed Celery task in a list

Tags: python, celery

I have a list of Celery tasks:

```
tasks = []
tasks.append(f.delay(...))
```

How can I get the first task finished (either with failure and success status)?

```
result = get_first_waiting(tasks)
```

Something like `Promise.race` in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that

```
for task in tasks:
    if task.ready() and task.status == "SUCCESS" and task.result:
        #do something
```

to check first task status, simple do this

```
first_task = tasks[0]
status = first_task.status
```

Comment: That would eat 100% of CPU. Do you know a resource-friendly solution?